# PHP for Loop with Table

Tags: php

Trying to output the following in a table:

```
   | 1 | 2 |
1  | 1 | 2 |
2  | 3 | 4 |
```

(top 1, 2 represents Column titles. left 1,2 represents row titles)

Code

```html
<?php
$rows_count = 2;
$cols_count = 2;
?>
<?php if($rows_count > 0): ?>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
          <?php for ( $cols = 1; $cols <= $cols_count; $cols++ ) : ?>
                  <th><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'col_title_' . $cols, true ); ?></th>
          <?php endfor; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php for ( $rows = 1; $rows <= $rows_count; $rows++ ) : ?>
            <tr>
              <th><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'row_title_' . $rows, true ); ?></th>
              
              <?php for ( $cells = 1; $cells <= $cols_count; $cells++ ) : ?>
                <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'cell_value_' . $cells, true ); ?> <?php echo $cells; ?></td>
              <?php endfor; ?>
              
            </tr>
          <?php endfor; ?>
          </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Question, how to get it to output the table above? so basically need $cells to carry on in the next row loop.

i.e Row 1 value 1, value 2
Row 2 value 3, value 4

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another variable to hold the count that goes across rows.

```html
<?php
$rows_count = 2;
$cols_count = 2;
$counter = 1;
?>
<?php if($rows_count > 0): ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
  <?php for ( $cols = 1; $cols <= $cols_count; $cols++ ) : ?>
          <th><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'col_title_' . $cols, true ); ?></th>
  <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php for ( $rows = 1; $rows <= $rows_count; $rows++ ) : ?>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'row_title_' . $rows, true ); ?></th>
      
      <?php for ( $cells = 1; $cells <= $cols_count; $cells++ ) : ?>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $post_id, $prefix . 'cell_value_' . $cells, true ); ?> <?php echo $counter++; ?></td>
      <?php endfor; ?>
      
    </tr>
  <?php endfor; ?>
  </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `<?php endif; ?>` somewhere in there. Maybe below the `</table>` ? Also, in the beginning of your code, missing `?>`, I guess below `$cols_count = 2;` before starting a new `<?php` block?

IMHO, this looks a bit messy, but maybe that's just me. I removed the `get_post_meta`, you can add it back in.

```
<?php
  $rows_count = 2;
  $cols_count = 2;
  $current_cell_value = 1;
?>

<?php if($rows_count > 0): ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <?php for ( $cols = 1; $cols <= $cols_count; $cols++ ) : ?>
      <th><?php echo $cols ?></th>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>

    <?php for ( $rows = 1; $rows <= $rows_count; $rows++ ) : ?>
      <tr>
      <th>
        <?php echo $rows ?>
      </th>

      <?php for ( $cells = 1; $cells <= $cols_count; $cells++ ) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $current_cell_value++ ?></td>
      <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: ignore that thats just added to the top and forgot! but yes should have endif; after table